# How to update MvvmCross?

Tags: mvvmcross, visual-studio-mac

I am using Visual Studio for Mac. I have MvvmCross v5.1.1 installed in my project. I want to update it (and all its dependencies and plugins) to v.5.3.1. But I get this error message in the output when I try to update my packages:

> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'MvvmCross.Binding 5.3.1' is not
>   compatible with 'MvvmCross.Droid.Shared 5.1.1 constraint:
>   MvvmCross.Binding (= 5.1.1)'.

Comment: Just remove all `MvvmCross` references from your project (VS4M right-click on the package) and "re-add" MvvmCross v5.3.1 (Or edit the project.config or project.json files manually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With MvvmCross version 5.2+ `MvvmCross.Droid.Shared` has been removed.

From MvvmCross [blog release notes](https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-52-release/#updating-packages-in-your-solution)

> As the nuget package MvvmCross.Droid.Shared no longer exists,
>   please force remove it first, and then update the rest of the
>   packages.

---

**Visual Studio**

You can run the following command in your Package Manager Console to remove it (Make sure that the default project dropdown is set to your Android project)

`PM> Uninstall-Package MvvmCross.Droid.Shared -Force`

**Visual Studio for Mac**

You can install [`NuGet Package Management Extensions`](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-extensions#requirements) addin (You can get the latest version of the addin from Github). Then execute the following command from the PowerShell Console Window (Make sure you have closed and re-opened IDE after the addin has been installed before trying to open the PowerShell Console)

`PM> Uninstall-Package MvvmCross.Droid.Shared -Force`

Comment: Do you know how to "force remove" it on Visual Studio for Mac? I don't think I have a Package Manager Console on this platform?

Comment: @Darius, see updated answer. You can download an extension to add support for running the powershell command. One thing to note, I had to download the extension file from Github version 0.12.5 and manually install in order to get it to work with VS for Mac 7.2.